# why is `reset` so much slower than `tput reset`?

Tags: terminal, sleep

In all terminals I can think of, `tput reset` is **much** faster than `reset`, why? (sh, bash, xfce4-terminal, lxde-terminal, gnome-terminal, and probably others)

I know the technical reason, `reset` issues a `nanosleep()` sleep syscall, while `tput reset` does not, but what is the logical reason? why was/is it implemented this way?

For the record, `tput reset` is over 1000 times faster than `reset` in my xfce4-terminal:

- `time reset`: real    0m1.002s
- `time tput reset`: real   0m0.001s

Edit: also, any reason to NOT add `alias reset='tput reset'` to `~/.bashrc` ?